# What is the limit function of the following sequence of functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{f_n \}$ be a sequence of functions on $[0,1]$ defined as 
$f_n (x) = n^2 x(1 - x^2)^n$. Then find $$f(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n (x).$$

I find difficulty to solve it. The problem is the factor $n^2$. Please give me some hint.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $0<a<1,$ what does $n^2a^n$ do?

Comment: For $0<x<1$ we have $x(1-x^2)^n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. But then what will happen?

Comment: Oh! I have got it! Taking $x_n = n^2 a^n$ for $0<a<1$ and $n \in \mathbb N$. Then $\frac {x_{n+1}} {x_n} \rightarrow a$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. But since $a \in (0,1)$ we have $x_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Thank you @zhw.